# How to clip before DrawUserPrimitive?

Tags: 3d, xna, monogame

In several other contexts, in 2D (Android' Canvas, GDI' Graphics) I used to clip my drawings before calling the drawing methods.

How could I achieve this with XNA?

I am drawing some primitives thanks to `DrawUserPrimitive` and have not yet found any method to clip these primitives. Is it possible? How?

Would changing the viewport or something like this permit this? When using a `BasicEffect` there also are `World`, `View`and `Projection` matrices. I have not dig into these yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. You can change the viewport

```
 GraphicsDevice.Viewport = yourCamera.Viewport;   
 GraphicsDevice.Viewport = new Viewport(yourClippingArea);
```

b. You can use an scissor rectangle... setting a rasterizer state with scissor test enabled...

```
 GraphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle = yourClippingArea;    
 GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = 
     new RasterizerState( ) { ScissorTestEnabled = true };
```

c. You can use stencil buffer and stencil operations.. basically this method is about creating a mask and applying it

d. You can clip before draw...

```
 (2D)
 if (yourCamera.WorldBounds.Intersects( sprite.WorldBounds )
 {
    sprite.Draw();
 }

 (3D)
 BoundingFrustum boundingFrustum = new BoundingFrustum( yourCamera.ViewProjection );

 if (boundingFrustum.Contains(model.BoundingSphere)
 {
    mode.Draw();
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I figured that I need some work before this step. I will soon come back to it. Thanks for your answer anyway, it looks like it's gonna lead me to the good way.